# Cassandra rebuild getting halt

Tags: cassandra, rebuild

I have a cassandra cluster of 18 prod nodes in 1 DC1 and 12 backup nodes in DC2 data center, few days before all backup nodes went down and crossed gc_grace period. now i am trying to make all Backup nodes up so have removed all data from backup nodes and trying to rebuild but it is getting halted with FileNotFoundException:.

Rebuild commands is : nohup nodetool rebuild DC1 &

(DC1 is prod data center )

```
Error in nohup.out file :
   Error while rebuilding node: Stream failed
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while rebuilding node: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.rebuild(StorageService.java:1076)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

**Error in system.log:**

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data1/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress-55080ab05d9c388690a4acb25fe1f77b/system-compactions_in_progress-tmp-ka-62-Data.db (No such file or directory)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:372) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data1/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress-55080ab05d9c388690a4acb25fe1f77b/system-compactions_in_progress-tmp-ka-62-Data.db (No such file or directory)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.<init>(SequentialWriter.java:82) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter.<init>(CompressedSequentialWriter.java:67) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:124) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.<init>(SSTableWriter.java:130) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:414) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:351) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runMayThrow(Memtable.java:335) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1134) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data1/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress-55080ab05d9c388690a4acb25fe1f77b/system-compactions_in_progress-tmp-ka-62-Data.db (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the FileNotFound exception. It's the fact that you are streaming system tables. System tables will be created on the node locally when it's started up. All the data should be streamed EXCEPT the system tables data. `/data1/cassandra/data/system/`

Which Cassandra version are you using?

If you didn't change anything that forced Cassandra to stream the system tables, I would say this is a bug.

Comment: I ran "nohup nodetool rebuild DC1" and did not mention any Keysapce.I am using Apache Cassandra-2.1.16

Comment: Its nothing to do with a bug as a straight forward "nodetool rebuild". During rebuild every keyspace gets pulled over and due to ongoing compaction there was a problem.

Answer (score 2):

While you triggered the rebuild in DC2, there were compactions in progress in DC1. You can issue the following command in all nodes of DC1 to see the compactions in progress

> nodetool compactionstats

As part of compaction, sstables would be merged together and the tmp "compaction_in_progress" tables would disappear once the merge completes. So streaming of those temp tables gets lost along the way from DC1 to DC2 and resulting in this streaming failure.

Also these compactions could be triggered by a "nodetool repair" initiated in DC1. So wait for repairs to complete if they are any in progress, to avoid this situation.

Since 18 nodes in DC1, I believe the storage size of the cluster is huge. A cleaner way to get around this situation is to pause compaction during the period of rebuild and rebuild one keyspace at a time.  So rather than rebuilding the entire cluster with

> nohup nodetool rebuild DC1 &

1. Issue the following command in DC1

   > nodetool disableautocompaction keyspace-name1
2. Then rebuild that keyspace in DC2, one node at a time

   > nohup nodetool rebuild keyspace-name1 DC1 &
3. Once rebuild is complete in all nodes in DC2 for that keyspace

   > nodetool enableautocompaction keyspace-name1

Repeat the above two steps for all the keyspaces until done. You can skip system tables like "system", which is local to that node and gets rebuilt automatically as you bring up that node (even with a empty data directory).

If there are too many application keyspaces to deal with, it becomes a lit bit of manual work.

Comment: Thanks for clean explanation. But seems "nodetool rebuild keyspace-name1 DC1 " doesn't work in my current version 2.1.16. i Stopped repair and compaction and it worked !

Comment: Good to know it worked. Remember to accept/upvote the answer.